# draw lines with an angle inside a rectangle in python

Tags: qgis, python, vector-grid

I am trying to make a plugin for Qgis with python. I have the four corner coordinates for a rectangle. I want to give the user the inputs, line space and angle (0 -180 degrees).

With these inputs, I want to fill this rectangle with lines in the direction of the specified angle and with the specified line spacing between the lines.

I guess what I need is the same type of code as for making a grid. But I can only find information about grids which are vertical or horizontal. I will try to code it myself, but if anyone have a webpage with information, I would gladly to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would proceed

### 1. Get the slope of the lines

I am not sure of the lines between which is the angle.

If between the line and the x axis:
[image: formula1]

If between the origin and a given point:
[image: formula2]

### 2. Get the parametric equation of the lines

This can be achieved with the traditional line equation [image: formula3] or with the point-slope equation [image: formula4]. In both case, this (the origin b or the point) will be obtained based on the spacing between the lines.

### 3. Create the segment

With the equation of each line, we can create a segment contained withing the rectangle. For this step, I would use the functions in the [shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/index.html) library (union, intersection,...)

### 4. Export that in whatever format